# Can't write to MYSQL DB after moving to a new server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've pinged to make sure I am connected to the server and I can obviously read it for reasons I don't need to go into. All of my DB calls look something like this:

```
$sql="insert into shoeboxvideos set vidid='$vidid', email='$email' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

And worst of all, before I moved to this new server everything worked just fine. I don't understand what could be blocking us from editing the Database. Is it possible that there are DB settings somewhere in the admin?

Comment: use `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); ` to know what is the problem

Comment: Use mysql_error() to show the error,May be your server have no permition to access the database

Comment: Use of mysql_* functions is deprecated.Take a look at mysqli_* functions instead

Answer (score 1):

- are you sure you're on the moved db? and not still connected to the old db?
- have you confirmed that connecting to db and executing query goes ok? `mysql_connect(...) or die('failed connect');` and `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` (change syntax if you are using PDO or mysqli.)
- have you checked mysql user permissions of the mysql user that is logging in? It can be that the user doesn't exist on the new location. Or even exists twice, with less rights granted on the one with the host that you are connecting with